# jQuery submit() is not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, asp.net-mvc-5

I try to override a `<form>` on submit behavior, so I use the next code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var form = $("#FilterForm");

        form.submit(function () {
            alert("Submit");

            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr("action"),
                type: 'POST',
                data: new FormData(this),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                    $('#Container').html(response);
                },
                error: function () {
                    $('#Container').html(loadingFailedStr);
                },
                timeout: 15000
            });

            return false;
        })
    });
</script>
```

This script block locates after my form. This form declared in the partial view:

```
<div class="panel card-0">
    <div class="panel-body">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("TasksGridViewPartial", "Tasks", new { StaffId = staffId, StageId = stageId }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FilterForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                        @Html.Label(Headers.DateCreate)
                        <div class="datepicker">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CreatedOn1, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="datepicker">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CreatedOn2, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                        @Html.Label(Headers.DateClose)
                        <div class="datepicker">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ClosedOn1, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="datepicker">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ClosedOn2, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                        @Html.Label(Headers.DateStart)
                        <div class="datepicker">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate1, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="datepicker">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate2, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                        @Html.Label(Headers.DateEnd)
                        <div class="datepicker">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate1, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="datepicker">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate2, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                        @Html.Label(Headers.DateCheck)
                        <div class="datepicker">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VerifiedOn1, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="datepicker">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VerifiedOn2, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                        @Html.Label(Headers.TaskNumber)
                        <div style="padding: 4px;">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VerifiedOn1, new { @class = "form-control", type = "number" })
                        </div>
                        <div style="padding: 4px;">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VerifiedOn2, new { @class = "form-control", type = "number" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Executors)
                        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Executors, executors, new { @class = "selectpicker form-control", @title = Messages.ChooseExecutors, multiple = "" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Projects)
                        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Projects, projects, new { @class = "selectpicker form-control", @title = Messages.ChooseProjects, multiple = "" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Statuses)
                        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Statuses, statuses, new { @class = "selectpicker form-control", @title = Messages.ChooseStatuses, multiple = "" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row" style="padding-top: 24px;">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">@Actions.Apply</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">@Actions.ClearFilters</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">@Actions.ShowAccepted</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">@Actions.HideAccepted</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

I render this partial view calling `@Html.Action("FilterPartial")`.
The most interesting is that I checked `form` variable in on document ready event and it was declared as need. But `submit` still is not called.
Where may a problem be?

Comment: Are you *sure* that the form is part of the page when the "ready" event fires? You would get no error if it were not. Have you tried binding by delegation?

Comment: I logged this variable in the ready function and it was defined and not null.

Comment: Do you have another form (or any other element) with the same ID?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, no, it's a signle form on the page.

Comment: It will always be *"defined and not null"* because that's how jquery works.  Check the length:  `alert($("form").length)`

Comment: To check you need to `console.log(form.length)`. The value of `form` will always be not null, whether or not any elements were matched.

Comment: @freedomn-m, yeah, you're right, sorry. I have one yet form but it has an another ID.

Answer (score 1):

`return false` isn't enough, you also need to block the default:

```
$(function () {
        var form = $("#FilterForm");

        form.submit(function (e) { // Pass the event to the function
            e.preventDefault(); // Stop the form submitting.

            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr("action"),
                type: 'POST',
                data: new FormData(this),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                    $('#Container').html(response);
                },
                error: function () {
                    $('#Container').html(loadingFailedStr);
                },
                timeout: 15000
            });

            return false;
        })
    });
```

Comment: Returning false from an event handler will automatically call `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Thank you, of course! But my problem is not this. It is not called absolutely, so all code in the function body hasn't any value.

Comment: Calling preventDefault on an event handler that *isn't called* will have zero impact!

Comment: @Шах, why don't you try changing it to `$("#FilterForm").submit(function(){...})`

Comment: @freedomn-m, not called? What do you mean?

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb, it was the first variant)

Comment: As per the question: *"But submit still is not called."*  So it's not calling the event handler, so changing the content of the event handler has no impact.